# How to move a border below some text down?

Tags: html, css, border

Suppose I have a snippet like this.

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 10px black solid;
}
```

```html
<h1>My name is Apujay.</h1>
```

How do I move the border right below the text down?

Answer (score 6):

Add some `padding-bottom`:

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 10px black solid;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1>My name is Bob.</h1>
```